# How do I return a Json objects sub object without knowing the objects name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I've got a Json object named `data`. It has the following content:

```
{"query":{"pages":{"856":{"pageid":856,"ns":0,"title":"Mededelingen","revisions":[{"*":"* News item number one\n* News item number two"}]}}},"query-continue":{"revisions":{"rvstartid":12446}}}
```

How do I go about returning `News item number one\n* News item number two`?

I thought I would get that when using the following code:

```
console.log(data.query.pages.856.revisions.0);
```

However, this code returns errors.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Presumably because some of the object names are numbers. **Also, I do not wish to refer to the object "name" `856` since this is dynamic.**

The structure of the object will always have the same amount of sub-items. The names of the ID's can differ however.

Is there a way of always returning the inner message? No matter the given ID's? Inner message in my example being: `News item number one\n* News item number two`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you what you want to return

```
var key = Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0] //return 856
data.query.pages[key].revisions[0]["*"]
```

Comment: Did you read the question, the number `856` can change.

Comment: +1 That about does it :-)